# How to set my local ref from a while to false in the ts

Tags: angular

In a while of elements in the html template.
i have a localref #fieldName for make some elements appears or disapears.
When my user click on the field i want to switch the local ref #fieldName to false in the ts file.

When the user edit has line. an input field appears.
when he finished editing his field and pressing the enter key on the keyboard I would like my local variable #fieldName switch to false for back to the initial state

```html
<div *ngFor=" let field of defaultFieldSelected; let i = index;">
    <div #fieldName>
      <span *ngIf="!fieldName.value">{{field.name}}</span>
      <input #fieldVal type="text" [value]="field.name" *ngIf="fieldName.value" (keydown)="editField($event, fieldVal.value, i);" fieldName.value = false" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
editField(e, value, index) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault();
      //Update the value
      this.defaultFieldSelected[index].name = value;

     // set the current #fieldName.value from the html to false for close the input 

      return;
    }
    //Update the value
    this.defaultFieldSelected[index].name = value;
  }
```

i not understand how i can get the current localref from a while.
i have try viewChild and Viewchildren.
@viewChild always take the first elem
@viewchildren Close all my elements and not just the element i have select

Comment: I am not getting your question here. Can you elaborate it better

Comment: You're doing it backwards. the point of truth is the model. Not the view. The view is rendered based on the model. Remove your local template #fieldName. Instead, add an `isEdited` flag to the interface or the class of  `field`. And use `*ngIf="field.isEdited"`.